# problems inserting dates with EF Core 5

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, dbcontext, ef-core-5.0

I'm trying to insert records in my Concursos table by this entity

```
public class Concurso
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    .....

    public DateTime FechaArchivo { get; set; }

    public DateTime FechaConsulta { get; set; }

    public DateTime FechaOrientativa { get; set; }

    public DateTime FechaInsercion { get; set; }
    ....
  }

 public int AddConcursos()
{
  _context.Concursos.AddRange(

    new Concurso { Id = 2077196, ...., FechaArchivo = new DateTime(2020,7,7), FechaOrientativa 
  = new DateTime(2021,7,7), FechaInsercion = new DateTime(2020,7,7),...
 );
  var dbResult = _context.SaveChanges();

  return dbResult;

}
```

But when I execute the method I get this error

[image: error]

any idea, please?

Thanks

Comment: If you look close exception is  `BadYearMontDay`. Probably  you are trying to insert invalid date.

Comment: year: 2021, month: 7, day:7 and year: 2020, month:7 day :7. What is wrong here?

Comment: The exception message doesn't lie. It must happen somewhere else.